# Adding a multiple buttons in 1 click

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a click event within a function, which doesn’t seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
<input class="text2" type="text" name="" id="text1">
<input size="20" id="high_light" type="button" /> 
<span><a href="#" id="add"> + Add more</a></span>


var count = $('.text2').val();
var divCount = count;

window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById("add").onclick = function(){
      if(divCount < count){
         divCount++;

         var input = document.getElementById("high_light" + divCount);
         input.parentNode.style.display = "";
      }
   };
}
```

Basically, I just want to add more buttons with 1 click. The text2 `class` in where I will enter the value of how many buttons I want to add. When I change the value of divCount to 1 (divCount = 1), it is working but it is just a fixed adding of button. I am new to this so i apologize if my code in not that organized.

This code is working, but it is only adding buttons 1 by 1 with a max of 4.

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("add").onclick = function(){

        if(divCount < 4)
        {
            divCount++;

            var input = document.getElementById("high_light" + divCount);
            input.parentNode.style.display = "";

        }

    };
}
```

Comment: `divCount` is equal to `count`, so your `if` statement will never run

Comment: Well, each line is processed in order with a delay in between, so it will create them one by one...

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I add multiple buttons in 1  click within the value of the text?

Comment: @GRD I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want to take the input's value & add it to the DOM as a <button> tag? Why do you have two inputs? Why are you using a <a> tag inside a <button> tag? This will help me to assist you

Comment: @ManuelAbascal. I only have 1 input and that is text2. What I'm trying to accomplish is example, then I put a value of 4 in the textbox and click add more. It will add 4 more buttons on the page.

Comment: @ManuelAbascal I hope that can help. Thanks

Comment: @ManuelAbascal Is it possible with jquery? I have yet to experience vanilla javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created an `<input>` that takes a number's value & adds `<button>` tag elements depending of **input's value** like so:

**HTML:**

```
<input class="text2" type="text" name="" id="inputValue">
<input size="20" id="high_light" type="button" /> 

<!-- Buttons will show up inside this <div> wrapper -->
<div id="button-displayer"></div>

<span><a href="#" id="add"> + Add more</a></span>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(() =>{
    let inputValue = document.getElementById('inputValue');
    let addButton = document.getElementById("add");

    addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let inputValueToNumber = Number(inputValue.value)

        let i = 0;

        while(i < inputValueToNumber ) {
            addButton = () => {

               let elementTag = document.createElement('button');
               let elementText = document.createTextNode('New button');

               elementTag.appendChild(elementText);

               let buttonDisplayer = document.getElementById('button-displayer');
               buttonDisplayer.appendChild(elementTag)
            }

            addButton();
            i++;        
        }
    });  
})
```

Check this **[working code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/mercenariomode/mbeg16c0/)**.

Comment: @GRD Yeah mate, no worries. If you got questions about the code, let me know!

Comment: Question about the let elementTag = document.createElement('button');. What if I want to Clone a div using this code. Is it possible?

Comment: The line `let elementTag = document.createElement('button')` creates a new tag element, in this case a `<button>` tag element & stores in a new variable `elementTag`. I stored it there so I could add a text to the new create `<button>` tag element with the line `elementTag.appendChild(elementText);`. You can read about `document.createElement()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)